# Using ruby gem net-ssh to configure a Juniper router

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, router, net-ssh

I'd like to be able to use the ruby net-ssh gem to make changes to a Juniper M10i router.  However, after sending "configure", I am unable to send any configuration commands.

For example, after logging in to the router via ssh, I'd like to issue the following three commands:

```
configure
show system
exit
```

Using the net-ssh library, i've tried the following without success:

```
# net-ssh (2.3.0)
require 'net/ssh'

session = Net::SSH.start(host, user, :password => password)
session.exec!('term length 0')
session.exec!('term width 0')

channel = session.open_channel do |ch|
  puts "Channel open."

  ch.on_close do |ch|
    puts "Channel is closing!"
  end

  ch.on_data do |ch, data|
    puts "Data #{data}!!!!!!!!!!"
  end

  ch.exec "configure" do |ch, success|
    puts "FAIL: configure" unless success
  end

  ch.exec "show system" do |ch, success|
    puts "FAIL: show system" unless success
  end

  ch.exec "exit" do |ch, success|
    puts "FAIL: exit" unless success
  end
end
session.loop
```

Upon execution I get the following output:

```
Channel open.
FAIL: show system
FAIL: exit
Data Entering configuration mode
!!!!!!!!!!
Channel is closing!
```

So how do I correctly pass the "show system" command after "configure"?

**SOLVED:**

I stumbled across the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6807178/152852

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/6807178/152852, the additional gem "**net-ssh-telnet**" provides the exact behavior that I am looking for.

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/ssh/telnet'

session = Net::SSH.start(host, user, :password => password)
t = Net::SSH::Telnet.new("Session" => session, "Prompt" => prompt)

puts t.cmd 'configure'
puts t.cmd 'show | compare'
puts t.cmd 'exit'
puts t.cmd 'exit'
```

Comment: is there anyway to avoid specifying the "Prompt" ?  If I do not correctly specify the "Prompt", my script will hang.

Comment: You don't have to specify the prompt it comes with a default, and yours might match the default.

Comment: thanks, the Prompt thingy and script hanging kind of puzzled me a lot for a while,  until I had a look at your post. +1'd

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a super old question but for reference I've found two ruby libraries that wrap telnet/ SSH sessions specifically for Cisco/ Juniper switch automation:

- [expect4r](https://github.com/jesnault/expect4r) (Cisco iOS/ Juniper JunOS)
- [ruby-cisco](https://github.com/jtimberman/ruby-cisco)